# How do I put single word as an array to a list in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, arraylist

I need to make such a list of words in python:

```
list_of_words = ['saffron'], ['aloha'], ['leave'],['cola'],['packing']\
```

by choosing some random words from other `word_bank = ['cola', 'home', 'undone', 'some', 'good', ....]` unless, let's say `len(list_of_words)=15`

I have never used that before. What is it called? 
Where should I search for it? 
How do I obtain such a list?

Comment: Do you want a list of lists or what?

Comment: list_of_words  = ['..'], ['..'] is invalid. You have to write list_of_words = [[..], [..], ..]

Comment: I just want to obtain the result given by first sample line. So words in arrays separated by comma, ending with '\'. I don't know what I should name it

Comment: Do you want a string?

Comment: You want to produce a list of random words, using `word_bank` as input, and for the new list to contain 15 words? You'd want `for` and `random.randint(min, max)` to build it. It's unclear exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Actually, its working here: [link] http://bryanhelmig.com/python-crossword-puzzle-generator/  pretty fine. I wanted to substitute words (no legend) with my own words, but I needed them to be put randomly from other array rather then typing them there.

Comment: Ah you are right, my bad. What you see here is a tuple. The \ is only there to tell python to basically ignore the next newline. If you want to randomly generate the tuple yourself you don't need any of that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that is what you are looking for:

```
import random
word_bank = ['cola', 'home', 'undone', 'some', 'good']
tuple([[x] for x in random.sample(word_bank, 5)])
```

Possible output:

> (['cola'], ['some'], ['good'], ['undone'], ['home'])

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to what I believe you are saying:

```
import random
list_of_words = []
word_bank = ['cola', 'home', 'undone', 'some', 'good']

while len(list_of_words)<15:
    list_of_words.append(random.choice(word_bank))
```

this will create an empty list, and then append a random choice from word_bank onto this list. I wasn't sure exactly why you wanted a list of lists, but this will put it into a format similar to word_bank.